# How to remove the UI of network locked?

Tags: android

I am developing a mobile phone based on Android.I want to remove the UI of network locked.How can I do this?Where is the locked files?Thanks

Comment: 7 question, not even a single accepted answer? strange!

Comment: Please, explain a little better what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in the developer documentation explains about this.

Comment: @Ted: It does? Interpret the OP's question for me then point me at the section in the 'Painless Threading' article which explains it.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - I interpreted the question to be about not blocking the UI thread with network activity. But perhaps I misunderstood the OP.

Comment: @MisterSquonk and Ted can you really interpret anything from this?

Comment: @Aleadam: Nope, I don't understand what the OP is asking. I could make wild guesses but I don't think they'd help.

Comment: @Aleadam - I'm with MisterSquonk on this. Blocking the UI thread was the only thing I could think OP might have been talking about, but who knows.

Comment: I kindly invite you to join me in the closing vote, then.

Comment: I want to know the  network locked files.Thanks.